# VS2017 stb_image.h

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am reading Joey de Vries' [*Learn OpenGL*](https://learnopengl.com/) Chapter 7. It shows how to use stb_image.h. I changed one line from the code itself. (The line with the filesystem.h is also removed.)

```
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("resources/textures/container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
```

The resource loads in Windows Explorer (after removing the slashes.) Why does it not work here?

> ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ
>   ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: PROGRAM
>
> ### Vertex info
>
> (0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position
>
> ---

### ADD: SOLUTION

As a commentator pointed-out, it is a shader issue. The shaders needed to be placed in the correct directory to load properly.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the image. Thats an shader compilation error.

Comment: Is the entry point going to be the Shader constructor? And, it's not finding those files?
   Shader ourShader("4.1.texture.vs", "4.1.texture.fs");

Comment: Got it now. If you put it as an answer I'd mark it correct.